# Display text vertically start from bottom to top and rotate text at 45 degrees in rdlc 2010

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I want to display text in text box of ssrs 2010 and rotate that text in 45 degree angle and display text from bottom to top but the only option available in text box properties is Rotate270.

is there any option available or should i write a custom expression to achieve this ?

I am using visual studio 2010 and local report (RDLC file).

Comment: this isn't possible, only horizontal, vertical and 270 degrees are allowed.

Comment: [You can create images of the text rotated however you want and display the images.](https://sqljason.com/2011/01/rotate-text-in-ssrs.html)